# SQL group by AVG mark of JOIN of 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have 3 tables:

Student:

```
id: int AUTO_INCREMENT
first_name: char(30)
last_name: char(30)
```

Marks:

```
id: int AUTO_INCREMENT
mark: int
```

Subject:

```
id: int AUTO_INCREMENT
name: char(30)
stud_id int
mark_id int
```

Where `id` in all columns is Primary key, and `stud_id int, mark_id int` from **Subject** table are secondary keys.

How is it possible to get the first name, last name and average mark of all students who have average mark above 8.5 (out of 10) at maths?

Here I started to write the query, but I don't know how to use the AVG function, alias and Group By function

```
SELECT student.first, student.last, ??? as avg_mark 
FROM subject
JOIN student on student.ID = subject.stud_id
JOIN marks on marks.id = subject.mark_id
Where ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) and [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) have an `avg` function (AFAIK, it's defined by the ANSI SQL standard). Note that it's an aggregate function though, so you can't use the `where` clause to apply a condition to it - you need to use the `having` clause instead:

```
SELECT   student.first_name, student.last_name, AVG(mark) avg_mark 
FROM     subject
JOIN     student on student.ID = subject.stud_id
JOIN     marks on marks.id = subject.mark_id
GROUP BY student.first, student.last
HAVING   AVG(mark) > 8.5
```

Comment: @Gholamali-Irani since `mark` only appears in one of your tables, you don't need to fully qualify it - but you definitely can if you prefer to.

Comment: There is no need of "as" keyword to show an alias? and how to specify that average of 8.5 is at 'math' subj?

Comment: Column name should be first_name, last_name. Because there is no column regarding only first and last.

Answer (score 1):

Use AVG with the HAVING clause.

Use the alias in the FROM clause next to each table name.

GROUP BY comes last